# O que devo alterarar no Git para o Git Bash abrir no meu diretório de projetos no windows 10?

Tags: git

Eu fiz as alterações no campo (iniciar em:) mas não funcionou. 
Alguma sugestão para este problema?

[image: Propriedades do Git Bash]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta remover a seguinte instrução do campo Destino. E apontar o diretório padrão como você fez no campo "Iniciar em".

```
--cd-to-home
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Muito Obrigado!

Comment: @Marcio Ótimo. Caso veja como uma solução que possa ajudar outras pessoas, sinalize a mesma como correta. Abraço.